# Exporting jasper report to zebra printer not printing it completely

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I have the following code for printing an invoice to zt410-300dpi printer:

```
private static void jasperPrint56(JasperPrint jasperPrint, String printerName) throws JRException, IOException {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet(new PrinterName(printerName, null));
    PrintService[] printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, printServiceAttributeSet);
    int selectedService = 0;
    try {
        job.setPrintService(printService[selectedService]);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
    }
    JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));

    SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration();
    configuration.setPrintService(job.getPrintService());
    configuration.setPrintRequestAttributeSet(printRequestAttributeSet);
    configuration.setPrintServiceAttributeSet(printServiceAttributeSet);
    configuration.setDisplayPageDialog(false);
    configuration.setDisplayPrintDialog(false);
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();
}
```

This doesn't print the complete report and is only printing about 30% of it.
In the jrxml file, I have defined page width and height as follows:

pageWidth="288" pageHeight="432"

Which is 4 in x 6 in after converting for 72 dpi of jasper

In the printer properties, I have set the page size as 4x6 as well.

Comment: Can you be more specific of what the result is? Is your page landscape? Does it just stop at 30% or does only 30% cover the entire page (stretch)?

Comment: It is printing only upper left portion of the page. The page is portrait

Comment: The upper left portion of the report covers the entire page of jasper print-out